# What is the query limit on Yahoo's Finance API?

Tags: yahoo-finance

What is the query limit for Yahoo's Finance API? Or where is the documentation that describes the limit?

For all of Yahoo's API's I've only been able to find general documentation for all API's. If you know where the documentation is for Yahoo's Finance API that'd also be appreciated. (I've been searching for a few days on Google, and on Yahoo's API sites, finally turned to friends at SO)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Yahoo finance have data request upper limit. Is there an alternative or workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888662/does-yahoo-finance-have-data-request-upper-limit-is-there-an-alternative-or-wor) The answer at that link says that no limit was mentioned. However, this could be old information; in which case this question should remain open.

Comment: I hit my limit at around 250 calls today.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [Yahoo Query Language Usage Information and Limits](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/overview.html#usage-information-and-limits) page. This is for all of the YQL APIs, not just the Finance API.

**YQL Rate Limits:**

[image: YQL Rate Limits]

What this means:

- Using the Public API (without authentication), you are limited to
  2,000 requests per hour per IP (or up to a total of 48,000 requests a day).
- Using the Private API (with OAuth authentication using an [API Key](https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/)), you are limited to
  20,000 requests per hour per IP and you are limited to 100,000 requests per day per API Key.

*The above answer was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888662/does-yahoo-finance-have-data-request-upper-limit-is-there-an-alternative-or-wor/32913242#32913242) by me.*

Answer (score 23):

A 2020 update:

- YQL was terminated on Jan, 3, 2019
  Because of this, the older answers in the questions are no longer valid.
   [Archive has a backup of the link they mention from the day before the shutdown](https://web.archive.org/web/20190102193053/https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)
  You'll probably never need it, the limits have been changed anyway
- Yahoo finance itself was also stopped for a while, but it's available again.
  It's located at https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance (e.g. https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AMZN)
- I also wondered about the **new** limits but I can't find an official answer. Online everyone seems to have another answer, but it general it boils down "a 4 digit number" every hour when using the unauthenticated (free) version.

Comment: I found this question by searching for the docs about this API. If someone knows where I can find them please add them as a comment below. (I assume I'm not the only one that will end up here searching for this). At the moment the current version of the API is 7 and I use code I can find online to find out all possible calls and their usage.

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE:**

Rate limits in YQL are based on your authentication. If you use IP-based authentication, then you are limited to **2,000 calls/hour/IP** to the **public** YQL Web service URL (/v1/public/*) or **20,000 calls/hour/IP** to the **private** YQL Web service URL (/v1/yql/*) that requires OAuth authorization. See the YQL Web Service URLs for the public and private URLs. Applications (**identified by an Access Key**) are limited to **100,000 calls/day/key***.

However, in order to make sure the service is available for everyone we ask that you don't call YQL more than 0.2 times/second or 1,000 times/hour for IP authenticated users and 2.7 times/second or 10,000 times/hour.

Comment: there is no finance part of the question that I can see. the only question is about the query limit and Yahoo's API documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Yahoo's YQL allows you to query Yahoo! Finance data. Their usage limits are as follows:

- Unauthenticated: up to 1,000 calls/day
- Authenticated: up to 100,000 calls/day

See Yahoo's Query language FAQ for more details at http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/

Answer (score 1):

Here are the details on new request limits as of now:

| Type | Limit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GET Requests Per Minute | 60 | Number of GET requests allowed in a minute per user account. |
| PUT Requests Per Minute | 30 | Number of PUT requests allowed in a minute per user account. |
| POST Requests Per Minute | 30 | Number of POST requests allowed in a minute per user account. |
| GET Requests Per Hour | 360 | Number of GET requests allowed in an hour per user account |
| PUT Requests Per Hour | 100 | Number of PUT requests allowed in an hour per user account. |
| POST Requests Per Hour | 75 | Number of POST requests allowed in an hour per user account. |
| GET Requests Per Day | 8000 | Number of GET requests allowed in a day per user account. |
| PUT Requests Per Day | 2000 | Number of PUT requests allowed in a day per user account. |
| POST Requests Per Day | 1000 | Number of POST requests allowed in a day per user account. |

Source: [Yahoo finance docs](https://developer.yahooinc.com/dsp/api/docs/traffic/info/rate-limits.html)